# why i failed to build sqlite3 when build python?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, python-extensions

why i just failed to build sqlite?

does it have something to do with readline or _tkinter, or something else?

```
pes/libffi/src/prep_cif.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/closures.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/dlmalloc.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/sysv.o -L/usr/local/lib -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/_ctypes.so

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _tkinter           bsddb185        
bz2                dbm                gdbm            
readline           sunaudiodev                        
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

> **Failed to build these modules:**
>
> **_sqlite3**

```
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting /home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Tools/scripts/pydoc -> build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting /home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Tools/scripts/idle -> build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting /home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting /home/mirror/build/tmp/Python-2.7.3/Lib/smtpd.py -> build/scripts-2.7
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pydoc from 664 to 775
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/idle from 664 to 775
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/2to3 from 664 to 775
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/smtpd.py from 664 to 775
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Tools/gdb/libpython.py python-gdb.py
```

more details:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _tkinter           bsddb185
bz2                dbm                gdbm
sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name
Failed to build these modules:
_sqlite3
```

my system is centos 5.3

Comment: do you have sqlite installed?

Comment: And, since this is Centos, sqlite3-dev as well as sqlite3?

Answer (score 10):

There is a patch that can be found (and is discussed) at the following address:
http://bugs.python.org/issue14572

I had the exact same problem as the original poster, and the patch resolved it.

To apply the [patch](https://gist.github.com/msabramo/2727063/), from terminal in your python 2.7.3 directory:

```
curl -sk https://gist.github.com/msabramo/2727063/raw/59ea097a1f4c6f114c32f7743308a061698b17fd/gistfile1.diff | patch -p1
```

Comment: It's 2016 and I still have to apply this patch.

Comment: It's 2018 and the patch doesn't seem to help with Python 2.7.14. I now use export _PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=1 before running ./configure. This causes setup.py to think it’s a cross platform build and avoid actually importing the modules into python and avoids final test of modules.